# Flipped barchart of frequency tables in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the `data` below,  I have 6 columns made of character elements. I was wondering how I could plot the frequency of each of the columns as a faceted, flipped barchart in `ggplot2`?

```
library(tidyverse)
g <- read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hkil/m/master/presurv.csv')
data <- select(g, contains(paste0(26079941:26079946)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following :

- Get the data in long format.
- extract the relevant language from column name
- Use `str_wrap` to get labels in different lines since they are long.
- `count` each column and option combination.
- plot the data.

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  mutate(name = str_extract(name, '(?<=using\\s)\\w+(-\\w+)?'), 
         value = str_wrap(value, 10)) %>%
  count(name, value) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(value, n, fill = name) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(.~name) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  guides(fill=FALSE)
```

For the given data it returns this plot :

[image]

Comment: Play around with length of `str_wrap` I think. You can try with `str_wrap(value, 15)`

Comment: Ideally for `ggplot2` it is better to have data in long format. I don't know how to achieve the same output keep data wide.

Comment: You can define your own rule to extract the language from `name`. I came up with above regex based on data provided. Maybe you can list all the languages present in the data and extract. `str_extract(name, '\\bSPSS\\b|\\bSAS\\b|\\bR\\b|\\bExcel\\b')` . Add more languages as per your data.